# How to let distcc use the specified compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, distcc

I have two gcc versions installed on my linux host, one is `4.8.1`, another is `4.4.7`. I want to use **4.8.1** while compile my code. 
After i set distcc, `gcc -v` will print the collect **4.8.1**, but `distcc -v` will still print **4.4.7**.

So when i use `pump make -j4 CC=distcc CXX=distcc` to compile my project, it will pop below error:

> cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

It seems that distcc don't use the correct compiler. How can i specified the compiler for distcc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still didn't find the easy way, but can compile like below:

> GCC_HOME=/path/of/gcc make -j4
>   CC="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$GCC_HOME/mpfr-3.1.2/lib:$GCC_HOME/mpc-1.0.1/lib:$GCC_HOME/gmp-5.1.2/lib:$GCC_HOME/lib:$GCC_HOME/lib64
>   distcc $GCC_HOME/bin/gcc" 
>   CXX="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$GCC_HOME/mpfr-3.1.2/lib:$GCC_HOME/mpc-1.0.1/lib:$GCC_HOME/gmp-5.1.2/lib:$GCC_HOME/lib:$GCC_HOME/lib64
>   distcc $GCC_HOME/bin/g++"

But in my invironment, distcc still can't work for pump mode